# DataBase session monitoring via JMX

Tags: java, jmx

i work on jboss as 7, is there a way to monitor the database sessions
(see the number of sessions,kill a session ...) via JMX?
i try to use the jboss Jconsole, but i'm not find this informations.
can you help me please?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using MBean which would be available via JMX.
Of course, in this approach, you need to do some programming to list down your session on JMX console. But I am sure it is very easy to do and all GUI interface would be JMX to use this feature.

See some good tutorial here - http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t49130.html

Comment: i failed to create an MBean wich do this,i'm not professional in JMX :(

Comment: JMX are very very simple to write, as simple as writing a class with main(). But the logic inside the JMX method is what you would have to write. I can help you with writing a JMX application which will say return an airthematic sum, but enumerating DB sessions and killing them need expertise in SQL at DBA level, which you need to write.

Comment: OK thanks,i write this MBean and it work successfully,thank you for your idea